# Get a List<string> of variables within a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, ef-code-first

I currently have a `List<T>` made up of the following class:

```
int id { get; set; }
string title { get; set; }
string description { get; set; }
```

I want to create a `List<string>` of only **all** the title's in the List

Which would be the best performance way to do this?

**Edit**
My Description field averages 2k characters... I dont want that to slow down *only* getting titles.

**Edit2**
I am using MVC's Code first (Entity Framework). The `List<T>` is stored in the _context, which I query from to get the data.

**Edit3** IF possible .. Is there a way to get the Title AND ID ?

Comment: Why do you think that the `description` property could slow down getting titles? Is the list already initialized? Are you always loading it in a method? Maybe you can use a field instead then if you need it often. Side-note: you should follow [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx). So properties should be [pascal case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I've updated my question. When I call the _context in a foreach loop, then add the results to a new List<T> to return, it takes about 2 seconds for 2 results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I want to create a `List<string>` of only all the title's in the List

You can use projection via [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx).

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();

var titleList = list.Select(x => x.title).ToList();
```

See [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx) for more information on LINQ extension methods.

> IF possible .. Is there a way to get the Title AND ID ?

You can use an [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) to put all three properties in one list:

```
var entityList = list.Select(x => new { x.title, x.id, x.description }).ToList();
```

> Which would be the best performance way to do this?

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
var titleList = new List<string>(list.Count);

foreach(var item in list)
{
    titleList.Add(item.title);
}
```

LINQ will not outperform a simple `foreach` statement, but that's a tradeoff you should evaluate by benchmarking since the difference is negligible in most cases.

[Microbenchmark](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6294647)

Comment: I'm not sure why you link "Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ", though.

Comment: It explains the different extension methods of linq if the OP is not familiar with them. If you know of a better link I can swap it.

Comment: Using a foreach loop took me ~4seconds to get the results. Using the .Select() brought that down to about ~0.7seconds.

Comment: @Romoku: It's just confusing since it suggests that the performance issue is related to the way you use LINQ. If you just wanted to add a tutorial link, this might be better since it's more general: [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the updates @Romoku -> however, is there a solution like this for **Edit3** of my post?

Comment: As in all three properties in the same list or three separate list of each property?

Comment: So much learn in one day :D @Romoku your edit is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you're using Entity Framework, in which case you wouldn't create the `List<string>` from a `List<T>` -- you would query the `List<string>` directly from your `_context`:

```
var titles = _context.MyTable.Select(x => x.title).ToList();
```

and yes, you can get the title and id together:

```
var titleAndIds = _context.MyTable.Select(x => new{ x.title, x.id}).ToList();
```

this gives you a `List<T>` where `T` is an anonymous type that includes properties `title` and `id`.

Comment: +1 indeed. I am using EF, although the other variants of answers do infact solve this riddle. Although, I've updated my question to throw in another cog.

Comment: but only this one engage Edit2, not getting Descriptions into account.

Comment: if you wish to get ID too, you can create annonymus type by `_context.MyTable.Select(x => new{Title=x.title, Id=x.id}).ToList();`

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Got it! `Dictionary<int, string> returnList = _context.Articles.Select(o => new { ID = o.ID, Title = o.Title }).ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.Title);`

Answer (score 4):

```
list.Select(o => o.title).ToList();
```

where `list` is the `List<T>` of your generic type.